# I want to know memory management flow after runtime exception in iOS

Tags: ios, memory-management

When App is crashed by runtime error, what does memory management work??

Are all allocated memories released?

Answer (score 1):

When an app crashes, all execution is terminated and any memory the app was using is reclaimed by the operating system.